# UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver closes when activity finishes

Tags: java, android

I started using this library which shows a nice progress bar for uploads.
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Following the docs I added a BroadcastReceiver, however, though the upload runs as a service and is beautifully updated:

[image]

If the user closes the activity in which the broadcastReceiver was declared I loose the ability to respond at the end of the upload. What can I do to keep the reference to the broadcastReceiver?

Note: I tried moving the receiver to a separate singleton class but this did not solve the issue.

**The broadcastReceiver:**

```
public final UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver uploadReceiver =
        new UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver()    {

            // you can override this progress method if you want to get
            // the completion progress in percent (0 to 100)
            // or if you need to know exactly how many bytes have been transferred
            // override the method below this one
            @Override
            public void onProgress(String uploadId, int progress) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The progress of the upload with ID "
                        + uploadId + " is: " + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(final String uploadId,
                                   final long uploadedBytes,
                                   final long totalBytes) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Upload with ID " + uploadId +
                        " uploaded bytes: " + uploadedBytes
                        + ", total: " + totalBytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String uploadId, Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in upload with ID: " + uploadId + ". "
                        + exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(String uploadId,
                                    int serverResponseCode,
                                    byte[] serverResponseBody) {
                // At this point, the serverResponseBody has been completely downloaded
                // and is cached in memory, so no NetworkOnMainThread could happen here
                Log.i(TAG, "Upload with ID " + uploadId
                        + " has been completed with HTTP " + serverResponseCode
                        + ". Response from server: "
                        + new String(serverResponseBody));

                String response = new String(serverResponseBody);

                dialog.dismiss();


                //If your server responds with a JSON, you can parse it
                //from serverResponseBody using a library
                //such as org.json (embedded in Android) or Google's gson
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(String uploadId) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Upload with ID " + uploadId
                        + " has been cancelled by the user");


            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class (e.g. MyReceiver) which extends UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver, add your business logic in it and then register it as a broadcast receiver in your manifest (as shown below), with the intent filter com.yourcompany.yourapp.uploadservice.broadcast.status. This way you can listen for events independently from your activities and services. Change com.yourcompany.yourapp with whatever you have set as UploadService.NAMESPACE in the initial setup:

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action    android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.uploadservice.broadcast.status" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onProgress(UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
    // your code here
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
    // Context context = getReceiverContext();
    // your code here
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(UploadInfo uploadInfo, Exception exception) {
      // Context context = getReceiverContext();
      // your code here
   }

   @Override
   public void onCompleted(UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {
     // Context context = getReceiverContext();
     // your code here
   }
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT ! If you want to handle events using UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver, just do not invoke the setDelegate method anywhere.**

More at : https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Monitoring%20upload%20status